# Get number sequence after an specific string in url text

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm coding a python script to check a bunch of URL's and get their ID text, the URL's follow this sequence:

```
http://XXXXXXX.XXX/index.php?id=YY&auth=XXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYX
http://XXXXXXX.XXX/index.php?id=YYY&auth=XXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYX
http://XXXXXXX.XXX/index.php?id=YYYY&auth=XXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYX
Up to
http://XXXXXXX.XXX/index.php?id=YYYYYYY&auth=XXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYX
```

What I'm trying to do is get only the numbers after the `id=` and before the `&`

I've tried to use the regex `(\D+)(\d+)` but I'm also getting the auth numbers too.

Any suggestion on how to get only the id sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is to use `split`:

```
string = 'http://XXXXXXX.XXX/index.php?id=YY&auth=XXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYX'
string.split('id=')[1].split('&auth=')[0]
```

Output:

```
YY
```

Comment: That would be the approach I would take as well, but note that this approach assumes that the numbers (YY in this case) are _always_ immediately followed by &auth

Answer (score 2):

These are URL addresses, so I would just use **url parser** in that case.

Look at [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)

Use **urlparse** to get query parameters, and then **parse_qs** to get query dict.

```py
import urllib.parse as p
url = "http://XXXXXXX.XXX/index.php?id=YY&auth=XXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYX"
query = p.urlparse(url).query
params = p.parse_qs(query)
print(params['id'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include the start and stop tokens in the regex:

```
pattern = r'id=(\d+)(?:&|$)'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
variables = """http://XXXXXXX.XXX/index.php?id=YY&auth=XXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYX
    http://XXXXXXX.XXX/index.php?id=YYY&auth=XXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYX
    http://XXXXXXX.XXX/index.php?id=YYYY&auth=XXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYX""".splitlines()

for v in variables:
    p1 = v.split("id=")[1]
    p2 = p1.split("&")[0]
    print(p2)
```

outoput:

```
YY
YYY
YYYY
```

If you prefer regex

```
import re

variables = """http://XXXXXXX.XXX/index.php?id=YY&auth=XXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYX
http://XXXXXXX.XXX/index.php?id=YYY&auth=XXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYX
http://XXXXXXX.XXX/index.php?id=YYYY&auth=XXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYX"""

pattern = "id=(.*)\\&"
x = re.findall(pattern, variables)
print(x)
```

output:

['YY', 'YYY', 'YYYY']

I don't know if you mean with only numbers after id= and before & you mean that there could be letters and numbers between those letters, so I though to this

```
import re


variables = """http://XXXXXXX.XXX/index.php?id=5Y44Y&auth=XXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYX
http://XXXXXXX.XXX/index.php?id=Y2242YY&auth=XXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYX
http://XXXXXXX.XXX/index.php?id=5YY453YY&auth=XXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYX"""

pattern = "id=(.*)\\&"
x = re.findall(pattern, variables)
print(x)

x2 = []
for p in x:
    x2.append(re.sub("\\D", "", p))
print(x2)
```

Output:

```
['5Y44Y', 'Y2242YY', '5YY453YY']
['544', '2242', '5453']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex

```
import re

urls = ["http://XXXXXXX.XXX/index.php?id=YY&auth=XXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYX", "http://XXXXXXX.XXX/index.php?id=YYY&auth=XXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYX", "http://XXXXXXX.XXX/index.php?id=YYYY&auth=XXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYXXXYYYX"]
for url in urls:
    id_value = re.search(r"id=(.*)(?=&)", url).group(1)
    print(id_value)
```

that will get you the id value from the URL

```
YY
YYY
YYYY
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex `id=[0-9]+`:

```
pattern = "id=[0-9]+"
id = re.findall(pattern, url)[0].split("id=")[1]
```

If you do it this way, there is no need for `&auth` to follow the id, which makes it very versatile. However, the `&auth` won't make the code stop working. It works for the edge cases, as well as the simple ones.